# Repeated column in mapping for entity exception + hibernate 3.5.6

Tags: java, hibernate

Can somemone please help with the below error related to hibernate while starting my websphere server:

Basically, L_SUBLIST_DETAIL is my main table with a primary key. This has one to many mappings with 2 other tables L_SUBLIST_CSI_BU_MAPPING and L_SUBLIST_RULESET_MAPPING.  Problem seems to be sumwhere with L_SUBLIST_RULESET_MAPPING table where sublist_id and ruleset_id forms a composite key and sublist_id  is a foreign key referring to sublist_id of L_SUBLIST_RULESET_MAPPING table.

```
************************** Error ******************

Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Repeated column in mapping for entity: com.myProj.appName.ruleset.vo.LSublistRulesetMappingVO column: SUBLIST_ID (should be mapped with insert="false" update="false")
```

The java classes involved are as below.

**LSublistRulesetMappingVO**

```
@Entity
@IdClass(LSublistRulesetMappingVOPK.class)
@Table(name = "L_SUBLIST_RULESET_MAPPING")
public class LSublistRulesetMappingVO implements IBaseVO{

@Id
Long sublistId;

@Id
Long rulesetId;

@Column(name = "CSIID")
private String csiid;

public LSublistRulesetMappingVO(){}

public Long getSublistId() {
    return sublistId;
}

public void setSublistId(Long sublistId) {
    this.sublistId = sublistId;
}

public Long getRulesetId() {
    return rulesetId;
}

public void setRulesetId(Long rulesetId) {
    this.rulesetId = rulesetId;
}

public String getCsiid() {
    return csiid;
}

public void setCsiid(String csiid) {
    this.csiid = csiid;
}



}
```

**LSublistRulesetMappingVOPK**

```
@Embeddable
public class LSublistRulesetMappingVOPK implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Column(name = "SUBLIST_ID")
Long sublistId;

@Column(name = "RULESET_ID")
Long rulesetId;

public LSublistRulesetMappingVOPK() {}

public LSublistRulesetMappingVOPK(Long sublistId, Long rulesetId) {
    this.sublistId = sublistId;
    this.rulesetId = rulesetId;
}

public Long getSublistId() {
    return sublistId;
}

public void setSublistId(Long sublistId) {
    this.sublistId = sublistId;
}

public Long getRulesetId() {
    return rulesetId;
}

public void setRulesetId(Long rulesetId) {
    this.rulesetId = rulesetId;
}



}
```

**LSublistCsiBUMappingVO**

```
import com.myProj.appName.web.vo.IBaseVO;

@Entity
@Table(name = "L_SUBLIST_CSI_BU_MAPPING")
public class LSublistCsiBUMappingVO implements IBaseVO {    
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sublistCsiBuMapSeq")
@SequenceGenerator(name="sublistCsiBuMapSeq", sequenceName="L_SUBLIST_CSI_BU_MAPPING_SEQ",  allocationSize = 1) 
@Column(name = "MAPPING_ID")
private Long mappingId;

@Column(name = "SUBLIST_ID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
private Long sublistId;

@Column(name = "CSIID")
private String csiId;

@Column(name = "BU_INTERNAL_ID")
private Long buId;

@Column(name = "SOURCE_SUBLIST_ID")
private String sourceSublistId;



public Long getMappingId() {
    return mappingId;
}

public void setMappingId(Long mappingId) {
    this.mappingId = mappingId;
}

public Long getSublistId() {
    return sublistId;
}

public void setSublistId(Long sublistId) {
    this.sublistId = sublistId;
}

public String getCsiId() {
    return csiId;
}

public void setCsiId(String csiId) {
    this.csiId = csiId;
}

public Long getBuId() {
    return buId;
}

public void setBuId(Long buId) {
    this.buId = buId;
}

public String getSourceSublistId() {
    return sourceSublistId;
}

public void setSourceSublistId(String sourceSublistId) {
    this.sourceSublistId = sourceSublistId;
}
    }
```

**LSublistDetailVO**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "L_SUBLIST_DETAIL")
public class LSublistDetailVO  implements IBaseVO{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "sublistDetailSeq")
@SequenceGenerator(name="sublistDetailSeq", sequenceName="L_SUBLIST_DETAIL_SEQ",  allocationSize = 1)   
@Column(name = "SUBLIST_ID")
private Long sublistId;

@Column(name = "SUBLIST_NAME")
private String sublistName;



@Column(name = "SUBLIST_DESC")
private String sublistDesc;





@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval= true)
@JoinColumn(name="SUBLIST_ID", nullable = false)    
private Set<LSublistCsiBUMappingVO> sublistCsiBUMappingVOSet;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval= true)
@JoinColumn( name="SUBLIST_ID", nullable = false)   
private Set<LSublistRulesetMappingVO> sublistRulesetMappingVOSet;   



public Long getSublistId() {
    return sublistId;
}

public void setSublistId(Long sublistId) {
    this.sublistId = sublistId;
}

public String getSublistName() {
    return sublistName;
}

public void setSublistName(String sublistName) {
    this.sublistName = sublistName;
}



public String getSublistDesc() {
    return sublistDesc;
}

public void setSublistDesc(String sublistDesc) {
    this.sublistDesc = sublistDesc;
}



public Set<LSublistCsiBUMappingVO> getSublistCsiBUMappingVOSet() {
    return sublistCsiBUMappingVOSet;
}

public void setSublistCsiBUMappingVOSet(
        Set<LSublistCsiBUMappingVO> sublistCsiBUMappingVOSet) {
    this.sublistCsiBUMappingVOSet = sublistCsiBUMappingVOSet;
}

public Set<LSublistRulesetMappingVO> getSublistRulesetMappingVOSet() {
    return sublistRulesetMappingVOSet;
}

public void setSublistRulesetMappingVOSet(
        Set<LSublistRulesetMappingVO> sublistRulesetMappingVOSet) {
    this.sublistRulesetMappingVOSet = sublistRulesetMappingVOSet;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot have two primary keys @Id , in the same class LSublistRulesetMappingVO.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for ur reply. It is not a primary key but a composite key. And this kind of composite key is working fine for other tables where we don't have such complex relation.

Answer (score 0):

I have changed the order of below 2 statements and the server started.
Can any1 explain what was the issue?????????????

Old:

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval= true)
@JoinColumn(name="SUBLIST_ID", nullable = false)
private Set sublistCsiBUMappingVOSet;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval= true)
@JoinColumn( name="SUBLIST_ID", nullable = false)
private Set sublistRulesetMappingVOSet;

New:

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval= true)
@JoinColumn( name="SUBLIST_ID", nullable = false)
private Set sublistRulesetMappingVOSet;

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval= true)
@JoinColumn(name="SUBLIST_ID", nullable = false)
private Set sublistCsiBUMappingVOSet;